# jquery datatables: sort type numeric not working

Tags: c#, jquery, datatable, columnsorting

I have a datatable with about 20 columns. I have a Serial Number column that consists of completely numeric values and is defined as int in the database. I have spent so much time trying to figure out why this is not working but still no clue. I tried using sType='numeric' , type='num', num-html,num-fmt .. nothing seems to work. I either get sorting like the following :

```
1
1
10
100
```

or it doesn't sort at all. I checked my data and it does not have null or any non-numeric values. Database has completely integer values and I am completely stumped as to why suddenly this is not working. Please help. This is my code.

```
<table id="myTable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Col1</th>
            <th>Col2</th>
            <th>Col3</th>
            <th>Col4</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td title="Del">
                    Data1
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div>
                        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuLink">
                            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.Id })
                            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details")
                            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete")
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    Data2
                </td>
                <td>
                    &nbsp;@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Serial)
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
</table>
```

The following is from my Layout.cshtml:

```
var table = $('#myTable').DataTable({
                    "lengthMenu": [[100, 200, 300, 500, -1], [100, 200, 300, 500, "All"]],
                    fixedHeader: true,
                    // "bFilter": false, to turn off search
                    fixedColumns: {
                        heightMatch: 'none'
                    },
                    colReorder: true,
                    stateSave: true,
                    "aoColumnDefs": [
                        { "sType": "numeric", "aTargets": [3] },
                        { "bSortable": false, "aTargets": [0] },
                        { "bSearchable": false, "aTargets": [0] }
                    ]
                });
```

Comment: are you returning a whole data set or only the records by page?

Comment: The closing bracket in your `foreach` section is in the wrong place.

Comment: @AntonioAvndañoDuran: the whole data set

Comment: @Michael : That was a typo here. My app has it in the right place.

Comment: Why are you returning the whole dataset? use the jquery datatable with ajax to return only the records per page. https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/ajax.html

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be using the jquery datatables library. According to the docs there is a default sort column information that you can provide on the initialization of the table:

https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/table_sorting.html

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        "order": [[ 3, "asc" ]]
    } );
} );
```

**Edit:** It is possible that other features or properties used in the javascript library are breaking sorting. In general when troubleshooting these types of issues I would recommend removing all properties with the exception of the one you are using (order). You can then re-add properties to see if anything breaks functionality.

So in your code:

```
var table = $('#myTable').DataTable({
        "lengthMenu": [[100, 200, 300, 500, -1], [100, 200, 300, 500, "All"]],
        fixedHeader: true,
        // "bFilter": false, to turn off search
        fixedColumns: {
            heightMatch: 'none'
        },
        colReorder: true,
        "order": [[ 3, "asc" ]],
        "aoColumnDefs": [
            { "sType": "numeric", "aTargets": [3] },
            { "bSortable": false, "aTargets": [0] },
            { "bSearchable": false, "aTargets": [0] }
        ]
});
```

Also, not sure if that non-breaking space would impact the value of the serial ID in the html. I would remove it and try to achieve the spacing via css on the td element:

```
<td style="padding-left:8px">
    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Serial)
</td>
```

Comment: I had already tried the "order" and it was not working. I tried your suggestion of removing the &nbsp; but it had no effect :(

Comment: Saw another issue with using the stateSave property